# Ninja close-voting hindered by teensy drag area

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, close-dialog, flag-dialog

It's great that the Close/Flag dialog boxes are draggable, so you can see the content behind them.

However, it seems only a small portion is draggable:
[image]

Can the bottom chunk of whitespace, and the top margin up to the very edge, also be draggable? Then it would be much easier to grab and whisk out of the way to <s>close</s> save the day.